# How To Import / Use Immutable.js Within Worker

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, web-worker, immutable.js

I have been stuck with this for two days and have not found an answer to this question.

In my React, Redux app, I am using `immutable.js` for all object manipulations. I need a web-worker to do some computations & post the action back to the `middleware` for dispatch.

Using this syntax gets an error:

**Worker.js**

```
self.importScripts( "../../node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js" );
```

error reported by browser: `NetworkError: Failed to load worker script at ../../node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js (nsresult = 0x804b001d)`

How do I import `immutable.js` into web-worker file & how do I use it? Clearly the following `es6` `import` syntax wont work.

wouldn't work:

```
import { Map, List } from "immutable";
```

Answer (score 0):

`importScripts()` imports script files from external services in the context of the browser - the browser doesn't have access to node modules, so you can't import your node_modules there.

Instead try importing Immutable from a CDN, such as [CDNJS](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/immutable).

```
self.importScripts( "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.min.js" );
var map1 = Immutable.Map({a:1, b:2, c:3});
var map2 = map1.set('b', 50);
map1.get('b'); // 2
map2.get('b'); // 50
```

Comment: An alternative to this would be to use a JS bundler like webpack to bundle immutable into your web worker JS file first and omit the need for `self.importScripts`, but having never done that I can't give you an answer demoing it.

Comment: Thanks for this. This importScripts is not working for me either. Getting the error `Immutable is undefined`.

Comment: My apologies, you are correct. However, the library would be referenced as: `self.Immutable.Map({ a: 1, b:2, c:3 });`